# WCF Rest Code First Can't return a list in a feign key table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I don't understand something about WCF Rest and Code First. If I have a table Patient alone. I can have a list of all patient without problem but if I have an user table and the patient table have a foreign key on it. I can't have my list of Patient.
I hope I'm clear enough. You will find my code below
My Service
Iservice

```
namespace HandyifeService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHandyServce
      {
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "Test")]
     List<Patient> GetPatientList();
  }

}
```

Service

```
public class HandyService : IHandyServce
{
    public List<Patient> GetPatientList()
    {
        List<Patient> listpatients = (from pat in mobile.Patient select pat).ToList();
        return listpatients;
    }
}
```

Code First
DataModel

```
public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Patient> Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Utilisateur> Utilisateur { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_nom)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_prenom)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_adresse)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_ville)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_pays)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_Natel)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_Teleèhone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_nomMere)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_prenomMere)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_nomPere)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .Property(e => e.pat_prenomPere)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
            .Property(e => e.uti_titre)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
            .Property(e => e.uti_nom)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
            .Property(e => e.uti_prenom)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
            .Property(e => e.uti_login)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
            .Property(e => e.uti_password)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Patient)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Utilisateur)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.pat_id_utilisateur);
    }
}
```

Patient

```
[Table("Patient")]
public partial class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id_patient { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_nom { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_prenom { get; set; }

    public DateTime? pat_datenaissance { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_adresse { get; set; }

    public int? pat_npa { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_ville { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_pays { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_Natel { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_Teleèhone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_nomMere { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_prenomMere { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_nomPere { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string pat_prenomPere { get; set; }

    public DateTime pat_creation { get; set; }

    public DateTime pat_update { get; set; }

    public Guid? pat_id_cabinet { get; set; }

    public Guid? pat_id_utilisateur { get; set; }

    public virtual Utilisateur Utilisateur { get; set; }
}
```

User

```
[Table("Utilisateur")]
public partial class Utilisateur
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Utilisateur()
    {
        Patient = new HashSet<Patient>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid id_utilisateur { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string uti_titre { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string uti_nom { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string uti_prenom { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string uti_login { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string uti_password { get; set; }

    public Guid? uti_Id_cabinet { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patient { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the problem is?
Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Do you get any errors? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm using Postman to test my rest Service.  Postman send me  could not get any  response. it's like my rest Service can't answer because of the other table. Without  the link bwtween table, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't get data of your foreign table "Patient"

try this to set reference in your class then try to call this "Patient" table.

```
[ForeignKey("Your Foreign Key")]
public virtual Patient patient { get; set; }
```

Comment: use this reference i think it will help you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts